# Symmetry transformations, compute infinitesimal change

Tags: field-theory, classical-field-theory

I am doing classical field theory. According to Peskin, for the field transformation $\phi \mapsto \phi e^{i \alpha}$ i.e. $f(\phi) = \phi e^{i \alpha}$. That's alright. My problem is that he then goes onto saying for an infinitesimal transformation, the differential is $\alpha \Delta \phi = \phi i \alpha$, my problem is that I find something else

$$
\delta f = \frac{df}{d\alpha} \delta \alpha = 
\phi i e^{i \alpha }\delta \alpha \neq \phi i \alpha$$

I suppose Peskin is correct, so **my question** then, is: How in general do one compute these infinitesimal transformations, if my approach is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinitesimal change is supposed to be computed *to first order* in the parameter $\alpha$:
$$\delta \phi = f(\phi) -\phi = \phi\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha} - \phi = \phi (\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha} - 1) = \phi\mathrm{i}\alpha + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^2)$$
If you want to do this by taking a derivative, you have to scale the parameter $\alpha$ with a real number $t$ and take the derivative with respect to $t$ at $t=0$. For $f_t(\phi) = \phi\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha t}$, we get
$$ \partial_t f_t(\phi)\rvert_{t=0} = \phi\mathrm{i}\alpha$$

Comment: If we want all the higher order dependence of $\alpha$, would the OP's be a better approach?

Comment: @Secret Why would we want that? The whole point of considering an *infinitesimal* change is that you don't have all those orders.